# Status filter with relation Laravel

Tags: laravel, relation

My application has a table of products and their statuses. When adding a product, statuses are added that will be available in the future. Also, there are system statuses that users do not see. Getting the latest status for an item works well.

```
public function latestStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ProductStatus::class)->ofMany([
            'published_at' => 'max',
        ], function ($query) {
            $query->where('system', 0)->where('published_at', '<=', now());
        });
    }
```

But when filtering products by status, the query to the database takes more than five seconds with a number of rows of 2000.

Is there any way to solve this problem or the database structure is initially wrong. Adding indexes to the database did not lead to a positive result.